# Matlab absolute value squared

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I can't find a way in matlab to simplify this symbolic expression. `x` will be evaluated in a real number.

```
syms x
expr = abs(x)^2
```

I expect the result to be

```
 expr = x^2
```

Matlab gives

```
expr = abs(x)^2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your desired solution is only valid if `x` is real, thus you need to tell MATLAB that.

```
 assume(x, 'real')
 simplify(expr)
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the same as @Ander Biguri stated. However while initializing `x`, you can tell MATLAB that as well like this:

```
syms x real;    %Notice this
expr = abs(x)^2;
simplify(expr)
```

Comment: I did not know that. Interestingly `syms x real y` will create a variable named `real`

Comment: @AnderBiguri `real` is not a valid symbolic variable name :)  `syms x real y` will throw an error. You cannot even do this: `syms real`

Comment: It does not throw an error in MATLAB 2014b, it does create a variable

Comment: That's odd. It throws an error, *"Not a valid variable name."* in MATLAB R2016a